# Why doesn't a mutableState variable based another mutableState variable using derivedStateOf changed in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The `sortByState` is a `mutableState` variable,  `resultListAllMInfo` will change when `sortByState` changed, it's OK after testing.

And the `total` variable based `resultListAllMInfo` using `derivedStateOf` method, I think it always get the latest value, but  total is launched once with `EResult.LOADING` case.

What's wrong with my code?

```
    var sortByState by mutableStateOf(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)

    val resultListAllMInfo: StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>> by derivedStateOf {
        handelMInfo.listAll(sortByState).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), EResult.LOADING)
    }

    val total by derivedStateOf {
        when (val s = resultListAllMInfo.value) {
            is EResult.SUCCESS -> {
                log("Success")               
                s.data.size
            }

            is EResult.ERROR -> {
                log("Error")
                0
            }

            is EResult.LOADING -> {
                log("Loading")
                0
            }
        }
    }


  sealed class EResult<out R> {
      data class  SUCCESS<out T>(val data: T) : EResult<T>()
      data class  ERROR(val exception: Exception) : EResult<Nothing>()
      object      LOADING: EResult<Nothing>()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `resultListAllMInfo` is a `StateFlow`, not a `State` from compose. You call `resultListAllMInfo.value` inside the `derivedStateOf`, but that won't reevaluate when the value changes, derived state can only do that with `State`.

Comment: multiple options, I guess that best solution would be to make `resultListAllMInfo` `State` as well...

Comment: Thanks!  But it seems that I can't use `collectAsState()` in ViewModel for a `StateFlow`.